# (JAVA) How do I Remove the First Element in a Circular Doubly Linked List?

Tags: java, list, circular-dependency

I've managed to make the doubly linked list into a circular one, I'm just having trouble making a method to remove the first element. I've tried looking at examples for single linked lists but I can't seem to modify it to fit my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Linkedlist Class

```
package LinkedListS;

public class LinkedList {

private Node first;
private Node end;

LinkedList()
{
    first = end = null;

}

public void addAtStart(int x){
   
    Node temp  = new Node(x);
    if(first == null)
    {
        first = end = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        end.setNext(temp);
        temp.setNext(first);
        first = temp;
        
    }          
   
}


public void printFromStart()
{
    Node temp = first;
    
    do {
       System.out.println(temp.getData());
       temp = temp.getNext();
       end.setNext(null);
    } while (temp !=  null);
        
}

 public void searchFromStart(int elementToBeSearched)
{
    Node temp = first;
    
    while(temp !=  null)    
    {
        if (temp.getData() == elementToBeSearched)
        {
            System.out.println("Found " + elementToBeSearched);
            return;
         } 
        temp = temp.getNext();
    }
    
    System.out.println("Didn't find " + elementToBeSearched);
        
}
 public void removeFirstElement(){
   
 }
```

Driver Class:

```
enter code here 
public class LinkedListMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
   LinkedList ll = new LinkedList();
   System.out.println("Going to add elements At Start");
   ll.addAtStart(5);
   ll.addAtStart(7);       
   ll.addAtStart(9);
   ll.addAtStart(10);
   
   System.out.println("Print the doubly linked list elements");     
   ll.printFromStart();
   
   System.out.println("Search the following elements");  
   ll.searchFromStart(7);
   ll.searchFromStart(1289);
   ll.removeFirstElement();
   ll.printFromStart();
   
}

}
```

Node Class:

```
package LinkedListS;


public class Node {
   private int data;
   private Node next;
   private Node prev;


// Constructor to intialize/fill data
public Node(int data)
{ 
    this.data = data;
}

 // set the address of next node
public void setNext(Node temp) 
{
    this.next = temp;
}

// get the address of next node
public Node getNext()
{
    return this.next;
}


public Node getPrev()
{
    return this.prev;
}
public void setPrev(Node temp) 
{
    this.prev = temp;
}

// to get data of current node
public int getData()
{
    return this.data;
}
}
```

For the removeFirstElement method I've tried these solutions with no avail:
Attempt #1

```
Node temp = first;
   temp = null;
```

Attempt #2

```
Node temp = first;
   if(first != null){
    if(temp.getNext() == first){
        first = null;
    }
   } else {
    first = end;
    end = first.getNext();
    }
```

Attempt #3

```
Node temp = first;
    if (first == null) {
      System.out.println("There is no first element to remove");  
} else
    temp = first;
    System.out.println(temp);
```

Attempt #4

```
Node temp = first;
    end = null;       
    if(first != null){
        if(temp.getNext() == temp){
            first = null;
        }
    } else {
        end = first;
        first = first.getNext();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

After scanning a few other methods that is what I found that works:

```
     public void removeFirstElement(){
    if (first != null){
    first = first.getNext();
    } else {
        System.out.println("There is nothing to be removed");
    }
    
 }
```